# What is global error (in spring validation)?

Tags: spring, validation, binding, spring-validator

I'm checking spring-validation `Errors`(`BindingResult`) interface. It mentions global errors in contrast with field erros. What are global errors?

Comment: errors not related to fields... Hence global errors.

Comment: You mean errors related to the object given to the validator as whole and not with its specific field?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can register anything as a global error... (Like database is down, etc.).

Comment: OK. Is it the same as object error (org.springframework.validation.ObjectError)?

Answer (score 6):

`FieldError` ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html))

- registered via `rejectValue` ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-))
- attached to a field

  Example:

  ```java
  errors.rejectValue("name", "name.empty", "cannot be empty")`
  ```

`ObjectError` (global error) ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/ObjectError.html))

- registered via `reject` ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#reject-java.lang.String-))
- not attached to a specific field (either multifield or not field related)

  Examples:

  ```java
  errors.reject("password.mismatch", "Password doesn't match confirm password")
  errors.reject("optimistic.out-out-date", "This page has been saved in the meantime. Reload it and start editing it again")
  ```